# Setting up redmine on OS X

Tags: mac-osx, redmine

I am following along the redmine install instructions.  I am installing this on OS X 10.6.2 with mysql 5.1.41.  I have the database defined in the local Db; I can log into the local Db with the redmine user and use the redmine database, however when I run:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate --trace
```

Can someone add some meaning to the following stack trace:

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
can't convert Hash into String
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:1408:in `directory?'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:1408:in `fu_each_src_dest0'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:1393:in `fu_each_src_dest'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:840:in `install'
/Users/wrbarbour/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:1070:in `install'
/Users/wrbarbour/projects/redmine/config/environment.rb:60
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:111:in `run'
/Users/wrbarbour/projects/redmine/config/environment.rb:20
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/tasks/misc.rake:4
/Users/wrbarbour/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:617:in `call'
/Users/wrbarbour/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:617:in `execute'
/Users/wrbarbour/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:612:in `each'
/Users/wrbarbour/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:612:in `execute'
/Users/wrbarbour/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:578:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Users/wrbarbour/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:571:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/wrbarbour/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:588:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/wrbarbour/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:585:in `each'
/Users/wrbarbour/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:585:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/wrbarbour/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:577:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Users/wrbarbour/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:571:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/wrbarbour/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:564:in `invoke'
/Users/wrbarbour/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:2027:in `invoke_task'
/Users/wrbarbour/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:2005:in `top_level'
/Users/wrbarbour/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:2005:in `each'
/Users/wrbarbour/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:2005:in `top_level'
/Users/wrbarbour/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:2044:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/wrbarbour/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:1999:in `top_level'
/Users/wrbarbour/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:1977:in `run'
/Users/wrbarbour/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:2044:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/wrbarbour/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:1974:in `run'
/Users/wrbarbour/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/bin/rake:31
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:19
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What instructions you follow?

What is your versions of Redmine, Rails?

Does you update your redmine_dir/config/database.yml with your production database settings?

Comment: Steps I followed: http://www.redmine.org/wiki/redmine/RedmineInstall
Redmine version: 2009-02-15 v0.8.1 (from doc's I cloned two days ago)
Rails version: 2.3.4
Yes, database.yml has correct settings.  Was able to open mysql client with those settings.

Comment: may be yoy must use a Rails v2.1.2 with Redmine v0.8.1
see a table at beggining of this manual

or try to install Redmine from trunk

Answer (score 1):

It turns out my problem was with the mysql 2.8.1 gem as discovered [in this blog post](http://accidentaltechnologist.com/apple/fixing-uninitialized-constant-error-on-snow-leopard/)